# Print specific Strings of an Array in Gravity Forms?

Tags: php, arrays, forms, gravity

I want to print all form entries of Gravity Forms on my website. So once someone fills in a form, it gets printed on a self made dashboard. With the next code i am able to receive and print all data from the field:

```
  <?php
      $form_id = '1';
      $entry = GFAPI::get_entries( $form_id );
      ?>
      <p>
        <?php echo '<pre>';
         var_dump( $entry );
         echo '</pre>'; ?>
      </p>
```

This code displays the next code on my dashboard:

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(28) {
    ["id"]=>
    string(1) "3"
    ["form_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["post_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["date_created"]=>
    string(19) "2019-12-09 12:10:08"
    ["date_updated"]=>
    string(19) "2019-12-09 12:10:08"
    ["is_starred"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["is_read"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["ip"]=>
    string(9) "127.0.0.1"
    ["source_url"]=>
    string(43) "http://localhost/bewegin30/beschikbaarheid/"
    ["user_agent"]=>
    string(114) "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.108 Safari/537.36"
    ["currency"]=>
    string(3) "EUR"
    ["payment_status"]=>
    NULL
    ["payment_date"]=>
    NULL
    ["payment_amount"]=>
    NULL
    ["payment_method"]=>
    NULL
    ["transaction_id"]=>
    NULL
    ["is_fulfilled"]=>
    NULL
    ["created_by"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["transaction_type"]=>
    NULL
    ["status"]=>
    string(6) "active"
    [2]=>
    string(30) "Quentin Kaffka genaamd Dengler"
    [1]=>
    string(8) "Vathorst"
    [5]=>
    string(11) "Beschikbaar"
    [7]=>
    string(33) "Ik ben de gehele dag beschikbaar."
    [6]=>
    string(0) ""
    [4]=>
    string(0) ""
    [8]=>
    string(0) ""
    [9]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
}
```

But i only want the strings (30), (8), (11) and (33) to be printed instead of all the strings above. Anyone who can help? Cheers.

Comment: Well don”t do `var_dump( $entry );` then (`var_dump` is really rather for debugging purposes to begin with), but access the individual array items you want to output explicitly.

Comment: You can reference the keys you need the values of, e.g. : 
`echo $entry[0][2];` // Quentin Kaffka genaamd Dengler, or `echo $entry[0][5];` // Beschikbaar